# sudo pacman -S reflector returns "target not found reflector" on artix linux

Tags: pacman

`sudo pacman -Syu` returns

```
system is up to date
world is up to date
galaxy is up to date
::starting full system upgrade
there is nothing to do`
```

And then `sudo pacman -S reflector` returns `error: target not found: reflector`.

Also I get the same error when trying to install `libreoffice-still`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some context. It would also help if you could actually ask a question. I don't know if you want to know how to install this "reflector", if you want to know why you can't find it, if you want to know what it is or what. Did you try `pacman -Ss reflector`? What does that show?

Comment: pacman -Ss reflector returns nothing.

Comment: OK, but please ***[edit]*** your question and address the issues I mentioned. I still don't know what you want us to help you with. Also make sure to include the commands you ran and their output _in the question_ so people can understand. Also tell us what you have changed on your system, did this used to be installed and is now gone? Did it used to be found and now cannot be found?

Comment: No, reflector was not previously installed on the system. I am trying to install it for the first time. And no, it could not be found previously with pacman -S.

Comment: mention system specifications please OS version and other details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have the `community` repositories enabled. At least on my Arch system, that's where `reflector` is:

```
$ pacman -Ss reflector
community/reflector 2021.4-1
    A Python 3 module and script to retrieve and filter the latest Pacman mirror list.
```

I just had a look at [Artix's documentation](https://wiki.artixlinux.org/Main/Repositories) and found:

> As of June 2021, all Arch repositories are disabled by default. To enable them, install `artix-archlinux-support` and follow the on-screen instructions to activate the Arch repositories you want, most likely extra, community and multilib, which contain packages not yet in Artix repositories. Do not enable community alone as it contains packages dependent on others in extra.

So, according to that, you should run:

```
sudo pacman -S artix-archlinux-support
```

Then follow whatever prompts that gives you to enable at least `extra` and `community` and likely also `multilib`. Once you have done that, run `pacman -Sy` to load the new sources and then you should be able to install as expected with:

```
sudo pacman -S reflector
```